# Why doesn't postback/control events fire after converting a web project from .NET 1.1 to 4.0 with the wizard?

Tags: c#, .net, postback

I converted a web project form .NET 1.1 to 4.0.  So far I am seeing  not causing postbacks/events as well as some linkbuttons and checkboxes.  There are not multiple form tags on the page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you used to perform the conversion but the first thing I'd do is see if the events are properly hooked up.